# jQuery code doesn't work when put within head tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery code that works when I insert it inside a script tag within the body. But it doesn't work when I insert it in the head tag or include it as a js file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from your description you most probably forgot to put your script into a [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(function() {
    // put your code here
});
```

Then you can place this wherever you want on the page (`head`, `body`, external script, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Any script code put inside a head is not supposed to execute automatically. Unless called by a event listener. So if you have put your code in the head section its just a piece of functionality waiting to be executed on a call. This code can be called as mentioned on a document.ready( ) event handler or any other event call from the user.

Answer (score 0):

try these format

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()    {
        $('#arrow img').click(function()    {
            transferEmp('test');
        });
 });
</script>
<body>
<!-- other tags -->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()    {
        $('#arrow img').click(function()    {
            transferEmp('test');
        });
 });
</script>
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```